# Convert a string to hexadecimal control code for a Dot Matrix printer

Tags: javascript, dot-matrix, qz-tray

I need to send a string to a Dot Matrix printer which uses Epson FX emulation that would print a simple barcode. I am able to print it by manually typing out the control codes into a string.

This is an example from manual: https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf#page=327
[image]

I typed the data manually into a string:

`var barcode = "\x1B\x28\x42\x10\x00\x06\x02\x00\x7D\x00\x01\x41\x32\x33\x40\x41\x21\x43\x44\x5B\x5D";`

Then sent it using "qz tray" module.

This works well and the printer responds by printing the illustrated code properly. Now my struggle is actually giving it my own data and changing the last 10 string codes, I have tried many ways to encode a 10 character string properly, so far nothing has worked. Is there a way in JavaScript to do this?

**EDIT:**

Doing:

`var barcode = "\x1B\x28\x42\x10\x00\x06\x02\x00\x7D\x00\x01" + "1234567890";`

was one of the first things I've tried, and results in the printer sitting idle and not reacting to the command at all. In fact I actually found that the first command 1B does not work and I have to send it using `String.fromCharCode(27)`. The full working command that manages to print a barcode then becomes:

`var barcode = String.fromCharCode(27) + "\x28\x42\x10\x00\x06\x02\x00\x7D\x00\x01\x41\x32\x33\x40\x41\x21\x43\x44\x5B\x5D";`

and it prints the data just like in manual. Substituting the escaped hex data for `"1234567890"` somehow just breaks it and printer does nothing at all.

**EDIT2 , The solution:**

It turns out that when sending the data to the printer, I inadvertently skipped the control code that was responsible for setting the barcode data type, in this case it would be A. Without it the printer will sit idle. Working code:

`String.fromCharCode(27) + "\x28\x42\x10\x00\x06\x02\x00\x0A\x00\x01" + "A" + "1234567890";`

Comment: @KJ It's an example from documentation and I want to start off with it, then incorporate my own data into the barcode. Target data will be a mix of upper case letters and numbers with no special characters, so the data set seems fitting as is.

Comment: @KJ Sending it through the direct commands is not in the scope of this project, this is being printed directly from a website using qz tray module and javascript. It doesn't matter if I try to send it ABCDEFGHIJ, 1234567890 or the A23@A!CD[]. None of the strings will print unless it's encoded in that specific escaped hex code.

Comment: `None of the strings will print unless it's encoded in that specific escaped hex code.`. Hmm... this statement doesn't make sense, since you're using JavaScript escapes, they should be identical to the string counterparts.  QZ Tray does support non-escaped hex (e.g. `x41x32` -- without the `\\` 's).  That CAN yield different behavior depending on the encoding, but the string formatting / concatenation shouldn't affect the output.... Hmm...

Comment: @KJ I think this is supposed to be simpler than that. An example of real data that would be turned into a barcode in my application would be A1B2C3D4C5, judging from manufacturer's instruction, I shouldn't have to dive into the core of Code-128 construction. And no, the output string is passed as data parameter of qz-tray module, I don't send the data directly to the printer by other means than that if that's what you're asking.

Comment: `I don't send the data directly to the printer by other means than that if that's what you're asking`. For the record, you absolutely can, and it can help troubleshoot this problem.  In Windows, make a `FILE:` printer, print what works, print what doesn't, compare.  Then you can test these against the printer by copying them to the file device (e.g. `type file > \\share\printer` or `type file > COM1`, etc.

Comment: @tresf Updated the original post with the final solution. I just realized you're also the qz-tray dev. Good work, it's a great product!

Comment: `Target data will be a mix of upper case letters and numbers` Note, that according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) Code "B" -- i.e. the first character -- may be required for lowercase. <3. Amended answer to explain this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hex value of:

- `\x41\x32\x33\x40\x41\x21\x43\x44\x5B\x5D`

is simply the following text, encoded (or more properly, escaped) in hexadecimal format:

Pay special note to the first character `A`, per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128#Subtypes): (Thanks to @Thomas in the comments)

> - **`128A` (Code Set A)** – ASCII characters 00 to 95 (0–9, A–Z and control codes), special characters, and FNC 1–4
> - **`128B` (Code Set B)** – ASCII characters 32 to 127 (0–9, A–Z, a–z), special characters, and FNC 1–4
> - **`128C` (Code Set C)** – 00–99 (encodes two digits with a single code point) and FNC1

- `A23@A!CD[]`

You can verify this in JavaScript:

```js
console.log("\x41\x32\x33\x40\x41\x21\x43\x44\x5B\x5D");
// prints: "A23@A!CD[]"
```

So you can change your example to this:

```js
var barcode = "\x1B\x28\x42\x10\x00\x06\x02\x00\x7D\x00\x01" + "A123456789";
```

... or make it even more readable:

```js
var barcode = 
    "\x1B\x28\x42\x10\x00" + // Barcode command and data length
    "\x06" +                 // Barcode type k = Code 128
    "\x02" +                 // Module width m = 2 dots / 180 inch
    "\x00" +                 // Space adj value s = +0 dots / 360 inch
    "\x7D\x00" +             // Bar length v1,v2 = 125 / 180 inch
    "\x01" +                 // Control flags c
    "A123456789";            // Barcode Data
```

... or using QZ Tray's array notation:

```js
var data = [
    "\x1B\x28\x42\x10\x00",  // Barcode command and data length
    "\x06",                  // Barcode type k = Code 128
    "\x02",                  // Module width m = 2 dots / 180 inch
    "\x00",                  // Space adj value s = +0 dots / 360 inch
    "\x7D\x00",              // Bar length v1,v2 = 125 / 180 inch
    "\x01",                  // Control flags c
    "A123456789"             // Barcode Data
];

qz.print(config, data);
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @Thomas in the comments for mentioning that the `A` should be kept.

I believe the data is formatted using the Epson ESC/P2 barcode format, defined here, page C-195: https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf

Comment: The first character of the "Barecode Data" `A|B|C` seems to indicate the used "Data Character Set", so we should not change that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited my question, sadly this doesn't seem to work. The printer is OKI ML 3320 Eco if that changes anything.

Comment: @KJ the question was modified since this answer was provided, it has since been modified to use parts of this answer to better explain the question.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, I was weary of this since it was missing from the picture.  Answer edited to keep the `A`.

Comment: @tresf And that also turned out to be the culprit. I was missing the Barcode data type letter from the data itself. When changing the example data for mine, I didn't realize they included the 41 hex code (letter A) as part of barcode data itself, `String.fromCharCode(27) + "\x28\x42\x10\x00\x06\x02\x00\x7D\x00\x01" + "A" + "1234567890";` Prints the codes properly now!

Comment: That's great news.  @Thomas gets the credit for that one, credit attributed in the answer.

Comment: Amended answer to explain subtypes "A", "B", "C".

Comment: @KJ that's very interesting, however, dot matrix and thermal printers often offer a way to do this in the printer's programming language that avoids these types of calculation.   When the OP says "dot matrix", this can generally be assumed.    Here's a matrix of these languages, most of which, offer Code 128 rendering/printing in a similar fashion to the OP: https://qz.io/docs/raw#language-aliases

Answer (score 0):

The correct barcode 128C per font encoding for `1234567890` in some BarCode TrueTypeFonts could be `69 0c 22 38 4e 5a 55 6a` or `i"8NZUj`. The pairs of numbers would be such that "12" = x0c.

One problem is there are other TTF encoding methods with different shifts so we may need `D2 2C 42 58 6E 7A 75 D3` to get the same output.

However those software TTF may not work in printer encoding as Epson have used their own different firmware encoding system!

In Epson Esc Codes the C(ompact) ligature feature may not be used for the inputs, so all range C characters are used as if plain numerals.

Thus rather than, 12 encoded as 0C using TTF, in Epson Esc/POS it is simply "12" = x3132. For that reason 128C may become academic for input, it may as well be 128A or 128B.

So for Epson Esc/Pos the simplest range to use is the Data Character Set B range as it include all Upper, Lower and Numerals. To ensure a Check Code is added along with the Start and Stop codes use the following

From example start with `1B 28 42 10 00 06 02 00 7D 00` as per example then `01 42`

followed by Human data `31323334353637383930`
[image] verify via https://zxing.org/w/decode?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FYb7Ih.png

```
Raw text    
1234567890
Raw bytes   
68 11 12 13 14 15 16 17   18 19 10 21 6a
```

To test if the compact version is used in the C variant printout try:-

From example start with `1B 28 42 10 00 06 02 00 7D 00` as per example then `01 43`

followed by Human data `31323334353637383930`
[image] verify via https://zxing.org/w/decode?u=https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYBBP.png

```
Raw text    
1234567890
Raw bytes   
69 0c 22 38 4e 5a 55 6a
```